# how to disable the url for specific user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have an admins table that has some columns like `id`, `admin_type`, `name`, etc. Here I have two types of `admin_type`: one is "admin" and the other is "hod".

Now the problem is that I want admins that login with `(admin_type == "admin")` to be able to access all the admin URLs, but when `admin_type == "hod"` I want to limit the URLs the user can access.

I am using Laravel 5.2. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

For example, if a user with `admin_type=="hod"` accesses these links

```
www.example.com/admin/add-user
www.example.com/admin/edit-user
www.example.com/admin/add-customer
www.example.com/admin/edit-customer
```

and many more URLs, I want to show some message like `**You have no rights to access this link **`

Here is my database structure:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with [the built-in authorization services](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization)?

Comment: Also, please read [the markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format posts properly here.

Comment: @EdCottrell the link you send is based on auth componenet provided by laravel but i have done login sign up with core coding

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "core coding," but again, what have you tried? There are a lot of reasonable ways to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: my core coding means i have not implement auth componenet for admin side i have implemented auth component for users side. My question is the link you send is work on simple seesions that i have used for admin side

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't understand that comment. Why would you use the built-in authorization component for regular users but not for admins? As for your second sentence, I'm really not sure what you mean. Is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implemented a [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) for such a use case. Just execute `php artisan make:middleware yourNameHere` in your Laravel working directory and artisan generates the corresponding middleware class for you.

Then you need code like this. It's a simple if condition with an 403 abort in case that the user is no admin.

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->admin_type != 'admin') {
            return abort(403, "No access here, sorry!");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Your routes file (routes/web.php):

```
...
Route::group(["middleware" => 'admin'], function () {
       //Your admin routes should be declared here
});
...
```

Comment: You have missed one thing. you have not define admin in kernel.php as alias